# Crear agenda con arrays multidimensionales

Tags: javascript

Quiero crear una agenda con arrays multidimensionales en Javascript. Mi idea es algo asi: 
Evento: Concierto 
Dia: 21 
Mes: Junio 
Año: 2018 
No se muy bien como enfocarlo. Habia pensado en crear un array para cada campo descrito y en cada uno meter la informacion mediante bucles for:

```
var meses = new Array();
    var dias = new Array();
    var horas = new Array();
    var evento = "";
    //Bucle para rellenar los meses
    for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
        meses.push(i);
        //Bucle para rellenar los meses con los dias
        for (var j = 1; j <= 31; j++) {
            dias.push(j);
        }
    }
```

Pero no me sale como me gustaria... si alguien pudiera darme una idea de como orientar este problema.... Gracias

Answer (score 3):

Te recomendaría optar por alguna estructura bastante más ordenada. Por ejemplo, utilizar ***JSON*** puede ser una buena opción.

La estructura que te sugiero sería la siguiente:

```
document: {
    date: '2019-01-16T17:52:56.266Z' // Con una fecha con formato ISO, no necesitas tener un campo para cada parte de la fecha
    name: 'Nombre de tu evento',
    description: 'La descripción de tu evento',
}
```

Posteriormente puedes acceder a las propiedades de tu evento de tal forma *(por ejemplo, para obtener el mes)*:

```
// Regresa 0 pues, enero es el primer mes del año
const mesDelEvento = (new Date (document.date)).getMonth ();
```

Comment: Hola Daniel, puede estar bien esta opcion pero lo que quiero es hacerlo mediante arrays multidimensionales aunque sea mucho mas lio... pero lo necesito asi.

Comment: Quizá necesitaríamos analizar el por qué hacerlo de manera que requieres, quizá exista alguna alternativa. Javascript es un lenguaje bastante flexible y el implementar una opción más ordenada no sería problema para obtener cualquier otro formato formal que llegases a necesitar.